# How to restrict a method to a particular thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a method that for thread-safety reasons should only ever be used by a particular thread. If another thread tries to use it, I would like an exception to be thrown.

```
public void UnsafeMethod()
{
    if (CurrentThreadId != this.initialThreadId)
        throw new SomeException("Can only be run on the special thread.");
    // continue ...
}
```

How can I find the `CurrentThreadId` in the code above? Or alternatively is there some other way of achieving what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thread.[CurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx).[ManagedThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx)

Or you could just store a reference to the thread object itself and compare that to Thread.CurrentThread.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did not see CurrentThread. I must be going blind.

Answer (score 4):

Name your thread at the time of creation

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(..);
thread.Name = "MySpecialThread";
```

And check this condition where you want thread specific code:

```
if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "MySpecialThread")
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea. The nice thing is that you don't have to store the thread id anywhere. Unfortunately though I can have more than one of these threads, so I would have to generate unique names for them (rather than just using a constant, if there were a single thread), which would makes things a bit less clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something along the lines of a static variable (a global variable in disguise) to do this. It doesn't feel very good to me, but putting this method in a singleton object would let you have that.